# What animals were represented in gods in ancient Egypt?

Tags: egyptian, animals

I cannot find many animals that were represented as gods and I am writing an essay on ancient Egypt.

Comment: Closely related: [Why did Egyptian Gods have animal heads?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/18/why-did-egyptian-gods-have-animal-heads)

Answer (score 6):

Animals representations are quite common in Egyptian mythology.  Here is a partial list of Ancient Egyptian deities with animal associations and attributes:

**Lion: [Aker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aker_(deity))** 

<sub>Pat Remler: *Egyptian Mythology, A to Z.* Infobase Publishing, 2010, ISBN 1438131801, pp. 4 & 5.</sub>

**Lion/Hippopotamus/Crocodile: [Ammit, the Soul Eater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammit)**

<sub>Hart, George (2005). *The Routledge Dictionary of Egyptian Gods and Goddesses, Second Edition.* Routledge.</sub>

**Falcon: [Anti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti_(mythology))**

<sub>"The Contendings of Horus and Seth" in William Kelly Simpson (ed.), *The Literature of Ancient Egypt*, 1972</sub>

**African Golden Wolf *(formerly Jackal)*: [Anubis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anubis)**

<sub>Wilkinson, Toby A. H. (1999), *Early Dynastic Egypt.* Routledge.</sub>

**Serpent: [Apophis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apep)**

<sub>C.Wolterman, in *Jaarbericht van Ex Oriente Lux*, (2002)</sub>

**The Mighty Bull: [Apis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apis_(deity))**

 <sub>Kahl, J. *"Ra is My Lord": Searching for the Rise of the Sun God at the Dawn of Egyptian History*, 2007, p.59.</sub>

**Lion/Vulture/Hawk/Snake: [Ash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash_(deity))**

<sub>Hart, George, *The Routledge Dictionary of Egyptian Gods and Goddesses* (2nd ed.), 2005, London: Routledge</sub>

<sub>Francoise Dunand, Christiane Zivie-Coche, *Gods and Men in Egypt: 3000 BCE to 395 CE*, Cornell University Press 2005, p.344</sub>

**Baboon: [Babi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babi_(mythology))**

<sub>Hart, George (2005). *The Routledge Dictionary of Egyptian Gods and Goddesses, Second Edition.* Routledge.</sub>

**Ram: [Banebdjedet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banebdjedet)**

<sub>Handbook of Egyptian mythology, Geraldine Pinch, p 114-115, Oxford University Press, 2004</sub>

**Cat: [Bast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastet)**

<sub>Serpell, "Domestication and History of the Cat", p. 184.</sub>

**Grey Heron: [Bennu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bennu)**

<sub>Wilkinson, Richard H., *The Complete Gods and Goddesses of Ancient Egypt*, 2003. p. 212</sub>

**Cow: [Hathor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hathor)**

<sub>*Religion in ancient Egypt: gods, myths, and personal practice*, Byron Esely Shafer, John Baines, Leonard H. Lesko, David P. Silverman, p. 24 Fordham University, Taylor & Francis, 1991</sub>

**Fish: [Hatmehit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatmehit)**

<sub>Wilkinson, Richard H., *The Complete Gods and Goddesses of Ancient Egypt*, 2003. p.228–229</sub>

**Scorpion: [Hedetet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedetet)**

<sub>Wilkinson, Richard H., *The Complete Gods and Goddesses of Ancient Egypt*, 2003. p. 230</sub>

**Falcon: [Horus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horus)**

<sub>Wilkinson, Richard H., *The Complete Gods and Goddesses of Ancient Egypt*, 2003. p. 202</sub>

**Scarab Beetle: [Khepri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khepri)**

<sub>Hart, George (2005). *The Routledge Dictionary of Egyptian Gods and Goddesses*. Routledge. pp. 84–85</sub>

**The Wily Mongoose: [Mafdet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafdet)**

<sub>Wilkinson, Richard H., *The Complete Gods and Goddesses of Ancient Egypt*, 2003. p. 196</sub>

**Cobra: [Meretseger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meretseger)**

<sub>*"Essays on ancient Egypt in honour of Herman te Velde"*, Herman te Velde, Jacobus van Dijk, p71, Brill Publishers, 1997</sub>

**Vulture: [Nekhbet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nekhbet)**

<sub>Bailleul-LeSuer, Rozenn (ed), *Between Heaven and Earth: Birds in Ancient Egypt.* The Oriental Institute of the University of Chicago. pp. 61–62, 138</sub>

**Lioness: [Sekhmet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sekhmet)**

<sub>[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sekhmet)</sub>

**Aardvark/Donkey/Jackal/Fox(?): [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(deity))**

<sub>te Velde, Herman (1967). Seth, *God of Confusion: A Study of His Role in Egyptian Mythology and Religion*. Probleme der Ägyptologie 6. Translated by van Baaren-Pape, G. E. (2nd ed.). Leiden: E. J. Brill.</sub>

**Crocodile: [Sobek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobek)**

<sub>Bresciani, Edda. *"Sobek, Lord of the Land of the Lake"*. In *Divine Creatures: Animal Mummies in Ancient Egypt*, edited by Salima Ikram, 199–206. Cairo: The American University in Cairo Press, 2005</sub>

**Hippopotamus: [Taweret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taweret)**

<sub>Jennifer Houser-Wegner, "Taweret," in *The Ancient Gods Speak : A Guide to Egyptian Religion*, ed. Donald Redford (Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2002), 351-352.</sub>

**Ibis: Thoth**

<sub>Budge, [*The Gods of the Egyptians* Vol. 1 p. 401](https://archive.org/details/godsofegyptianso00budg)</sub>

**Baboon: Thoth**

<sub>Budge, [*The Gods of the Egyptians* Vol. 1 p. 403](https://archive.org/details/godsofegyptianso00budg)</sub>

**Hare: [Unut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unut)**

 <sub>Erik Hornung, *Conceptions of God in Ancient Egypt: The One and the Many*, Cornell University Press 1996, p. 82</sub>

---

To help you with your research efforts, I'm including a note about how I went about compiling information for this answer.

I did a search for Egyptian gods and found a [Wikipedia page with an extensive list of Egyptian Deities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Egyptian_deities). (*The list may not be 100% complete, but should be sufficient for undergraduate work. IMPORTANT: Wikipedia on it's own is not generally considered acceptable as a source, but the better articles will include citations to scholarly sources, which are acceptable. Any information that does not carry a citation is considered unreliable and must be externally validated. For university-level work, you are expected read the cited source material, which may involve going to the library;*)

Using the master list, I checked each entry, checked for citations, then aggregated into a list of animal-deities. For the most part, I avoided repetition of animals. (There are numerous other instances of Egyptian gods represented as lions and lionesses, which relate to warfare, including [Mehit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehit),
 [Menhit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menhit), [Apedemak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apedemak), [Maahes son of Bast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maahes), [Pakhet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakhet) and [Sheshmetet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shesmetet).)

The wiki for the well-known goddess Sekhmet has a distinct lack of citations, so I went to the Oxford Dictionaries.  For your purposes, this may be a suitable reference.  For instance, the entry on mighty [Apis](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apis).